# redux: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' during RTK migration

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

We are in the process of migrating from "old" redux to RTK. I have an async function that uses .then() but since making changes to the store configuration I get a `TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.` error 1 function.

I wonder if i have migrated to configureStore correctly?

my old store:

```
const configureStore = () => {

  const middlewares: Array<Middleware> = [];

  // Add router middleware
  middlewares.push(thunk);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middlewares.push(require('redux-immutable-state-invariant').default());
  }

  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );

  return [store];
};

export default configureStore;
```

new RTK store

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  preloadedState: initialState,
});
```

Comment: Are you using an `useAppDispatch` hook, or the untyped `useDispatch` hook? The latter won't be aware that your have the `thunk` middleware in your store.

Comment: const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

Comment: @phry would you say the store is set up correctly?

Comment: Yes it generally is set up correctly. Maybe add how you get `AppDispatch` and the code that is actually giving you the TypeScript error to the question? (I would assume that it happens on a dispatch, but I have to guess since you are not showing it)